# Mechanical Systems and Signal Processing LaTeX Template

Tags: templates

I am an PhD student and my supervisor ask me to submit a my paper at [Mechanical Systems and Signal Processing](http://www.journals.elsevier.com/mechanical-systems-and-signal-processing/) (by Elsevier B.V.).

I have looked in the MSSP site and in Google but I have not found any LaTeX template of this journal.

Anybody of you have wrote for that journal, or can tell me where find his template?

PS *I have found several templates of Elsevier journals, but no one for MSSP.*

Comment: The online guide says "It is important that the file be saved in the native format of the word processor used. The text should be in single-column format. Keep the layout of the text as simple as possible. Most formatting codes will be removed and replaced on processing the article." so I'd just use `article` class and as little tex markup as possible.

Comment: I think an editor of the journal would be the most reliable source of information concerning the journal.

Comment: one of my students hasthe same problem with another journal. Also Elsevier's latex template url disappeared too. I would also mail the publication office about it. But they responded quite slowly in our case. Fortunately I convinced him to publish somewhere else since I'm supporting the [the cost of knowledge](http://thecostofknowledge.com/)

Comment: Thank you @DavidCarlisle. I began to think that they wanted the source code, and not the PDF.

Comment: I am sure they do want the source not the pdf. (to be honest Your life would probably be simpler if you used word or open office or something) that way you control the conversion.

Comment: Instructions for elsevier journals are here: http://www.elsevier.com/authors/author-schemas/latex-instructions Do not forget to upload a version of your paper on an open archive [arxiv,HaL,...]

Comment: Thank you @pluton. I am reading the document and contain the generic answer (for all Elsevier journals). But it is a step forward.

Comment: Are there any news here?

Comment: Yes, apologize me. I write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is very easy, for this reason difficult to find immediately.

The only things to do is use the template:

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
```

and send the file .tex and all the attachments.

For this reason there no template: the revisor want work with the LaTeX file and, after, pass it to the editor.

Thank you!